# Force terminal to use binary from a different path

Tags: terminal, homebrew, python, path

I have installed [pandoc](https://pandoc.org/) using homebrew and the Anaconda python distribution using [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv). I've just found that Anaconda comes with its own pandoc binary and since the pyenv shims come before homebrew in my PATH, I cannot use the homebrew (and newer) version of pandoc.

This is my current PATH

```
➜ ~ echo $PATH
/Users/marco/.pyenv/shims:/Users/marco/.rbenv/shims:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/TeX/texbin:/usr/local/MacGPG2/bin
➜ ~ which pandoc
/Users/marco/.pyenv/shims/pandoc
```

Is there a way to force the terminal to use the homebrew version of a binary without breaking the PATH?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always provide the full path to the binary instead of using the PATH at all.

```
$ /usr/local/bin/pandoc
```

To make multiple executions easier, you can create an alias.

```
alias pandoc=/usr/local/bin/pandoc
```

```
$ which pandoc
/Users/marco/.pyenv/shims/pandoc

$ alias pandoc=/usr/local/bin/pandoc

$ which pandoc
pandoc: aliased to /usr/local/bin/pandoc
```

To make future executions easier, put this alias in a .profile.

To bypass the alias without removing it, prepend a `\`.

```
$ \pandoc
```

The ‘right way’ is still to modify your PATH.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what would be the 'right way' to modify the path in this case? I'm always a bit confused on how to mess with the path order while also keeping things like `conda activate` and conda in general happy.